# Would I can download eclipse and another programming tools on Dell Venue 8 Pro Tablet (Windows 8.1) ?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, windows-8.1, programming-tools

**I want buy *Dell Venue 8 Pro Tablet (Windows 8.1)*, and i need to know if i can downlode eclipse and another programming tools on it ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The Venue 8 Pro is a normal (albeit small) Windows 8.1 x86 device.